# Strtok_r() and moving the save pointer

Tags: c++, shell, pointers, strtok

I'm trying to tokenize a string for miniature cstrings "&&" and "||". I've been using strtok_r() to some good success, but due to either a lack of understanding in strtok_r(), or perhaps a misunderstanding of pointers I can't seem to get the parser to behave properly.

**The code**

```
121         char *cstr3;
122         char* sp;
123         int fc = findclosest(cstr2);
124         switch (fc){
125                 case 0:
126                 std::cout << "that's it"; //debug
127                 cstr3 = strtok_r(cstr2, ";", &sp);
128                 break;
129
130                 case 1:
131                 std::cout << ";"; //debug
132                 cstr3 = strtok_r(cstr2, ";", &sp);
133                 break;
134
135                 case 2:
136                 std::cout << "&&"; //debug
137                 cstr3 = strtok_r(cstr2, "&", &sp);
138                 break;
139
140                 case 3:
141                 std::cout << "||"; //debug
142                 cstr3 = strtok_r(cstr2, "|", &sp);
143                 break;
144
145                 default:
146                 break;
147         }
148
149        puts(cstr3);//debug
150        while(cstr3 != NULL)
151        {
152             char mustfail =0;
153             char mustpass =0;
154
155             int a = fcall(breakitup(cstr3));
156
157             if (a > 0){
158                 delete[] cstr;
159                 goto skippy;
160             }
161
162             fc = findclosest(cstr3);
163
164             switch (fc){
165                 case 0:
166                 cstr3 = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &sp);
167                 break;
168
169                 case 1:
170                 std::cout << ";"; //debug
171                 cstr3 = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &sp);
172                 break;
173
174                 case 2:
175                 std::cout << "&&"; //debug
176                 cstr3 =  strtok_r(NULL, "&", &sp );
177                 break;
178
179                 case 3:
180                 std::cout << "||"; //debug
181                 cstr3 = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &sp);
182                 break;
183
184                 default:
185                 break;
186             }
187      if (cstr3 != NULL){ //debug
188          puts(cstr3);
189      }
190 }
```

Rather than feeding the next command without an "&" or a "|", it feeds the line STARTING with one. I thus assume the parser only removed the first "&"

For a better explination, the following is output (line starts with '>' to denote input). Apologies, some debug statements are still in the output.

```
> pwd; ls

;pwd //debug
/folder/folder/folder/project //function works properly
 ls //debug
notrshell  README.md  rshell.cpp  shelly  supershell

> pwd && ls

&&pwd //debug
/folder/folder/folder/project
& ls //debug
```

Because of that extra '&', the next command gets interpreted incorrectly, is there an easy way to skip just that one '&'?

I've tried calling the exact same command again, for example:

```
176                 cstr3 =  strtok_r(NULL, "&", &sp );
177                 cstr3 =  strtok_r(NULL, "&", &sp );
```

assuming it would simply remove another &, but that didn't work.

I've also tried shifting the pointer to sneakily skip the extra &,

```
176                 cstr3 =  1+ strtok_r(NULL, "&", &sp );
```

but not only was that completely cheesy but it too did not work.

Is there something I can learn about strtok_r() or pointers that will fix this mess?

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` and the `string::find` and the `string::substr` functions.  The C-style strings are unsafe, and the `strtok()` function modifies the C-style string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews <opinion> I dislike that "C-style strings are unsafe" logic - C-style strings are definitely harder to use correctly, and have a number of potential misuse scenarios that a programmer needs to be aware of, but that doesn't mean they don't have their place and should be entirely abandoned. That sort of thinking would lead to "People die in auto accidents. Therefore cars are unsafe. Thus, nobody should ever use an automobile ever again." and other such silliness. </opinion>

Comment: @twalberg The question is specifically tagged C++ and the number of possible pitfalls with C-style strings that can be avoided with a C++ approach makes the C-string approach seem suboptimal *in this case*.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments, unfortunately much of the functions I'm using are in cstrings, and much of the architecture I have allready laid out is for cstrings, but I'll be sure to use the convenience of strings in the future!

Comment: What does the `findclosest` function do? What is the meaning of its return value?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this input: `pwd && ls`.

In the first `switch` statement, you make:

```
cstr3 = strtok_r(cstr2, "&", &sp);
```

After this call, `cstr3` points to the string: `"pwd "`, as, according to manual:

> Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token. This string does not include the delimiting byte.

`sp` points to... Well, the manual doesn't state it literally, but it most probable points to where it finished in the last call - in our case, just after the delimiter, which is `&`. So, it points to a part of our string: `& ls`. And that's what gets tokenized on the second `strtok_r` call.

I cannot be sure, but I guess there is a problem in the `findclosest` function - can you confirm that it returns a correct value here?

Anyway, from the manual:

> The delim argument specifies a **set of bytes** that delimit the tokens in the parsed string.

That means you should be able to use `"&&"` as the delimiter. This should solve the issue.

As you are calling system functions, remember that for some (most?) shells a single `&` at the end of the command puts its execution in the background.

Comment: Sorry, I was away, but `findclosest` returns a number depending on whether the next closest object is a semicolon, pair bar, or pair ampersand.  It works very reliably, it's just a bit lazy. Unfortunately, another function (breakitup) was also using strtok, and I suppose the behavior by intersecting the two became undefined. I've since run them separately with great results! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, successive calls to `strtok` and `strtok_r` should concern the same string - if you use another one, it'll get messed up.